Open a new hyperlink in same tab previously opened
I have two hyperlinks <A Href="address1"... TARGET="info"> and <A Href="address2"... TARGET="info">
When I click the second one, it opens a new tab.
How can I have it opened in the same tab "info" ?

Link 1
Link 2 Ideally, second link should open in the same tab as that of link1. If not, it could be due to the browser behavior or a conflict with other scripts or settings on the page. Try testing in incognito mode or different browser.

If you want to ensure that the link opens in the same window, you can use _self
<a href="address2" target="_self">Link 1</a>


Sorry, I just noticed that links are open in a new tab only when they are from a window which was open by the Javascript open() function.
The first <A Href="address1"... TARGET="info"> opens a new tab, but the second
<A Href="address2"... TARGET="info"> should open the link in the same tab, not a new one. Even a second click on the same link opens a new tab. This happens with Firefox ans Chrome as well.
If it is a question of security, I do not see the reason for.
